# Почему возвращается error для методов search() , contains()?

Tags: julia

При использовании методов search(), contains() со строками
Возвращается ошибка:

> Error: Loaderror: UndefVarError: search not defined >Error:Loaderror:UndefVarError: contains not defined

Code:

```
for line in eachline("file.txt")
  search(line,"test")
end
for line in eachline("file.txt")
  contains("test",line)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Первая ошибка

> ERROR: UndefVarError: search not defined

вполне красноречиво даёт понять, что метода `search` не существует. Вторая:

> Error:Loaderror:UndefVarError: contains not defined

означает попытку разбора неопределённых данных, причины могут быть разные (несуществующий файл, файл блокируется другим процессом и т.д.) Сам же пример можно переписать проще:

```
[contains(x, "test") for x in eachline("file.txt")]
```